# In Postman, how to define pm.iterationData() when NOT using Collection Runner?

Tags: collections, postman, postman-collection-runner

My use case is simple: I have a Postman Collection with a few requests, one of them is:

```
GET www.example.com/stores?country={{country}}
```

Then a simple Test:

```js
pm.test("Check number of stores", function () {
  var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(jsonData.stores.length).to.equal(pm.iterationData.get("size"));
});
```

So everything is nice and merry with the following Collection data used in the Collection Runner:

```
country,size
UK,15
US,32
```

However when I simply want to run this via the main Postman window, obviously the request and the Test fails. I can set a collection variable `country` to `SE`, but I have no idea how to set `size` in `pm.iterationData` just to try if my request and test script is working fine for another "country" - without running the whole collection/iterations.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can modify iteration data variable in runtime, but a workaround for this issue is to copy your request from the original folder into a new folder, then you can run the whole folder with only one request, you dun have then to run all the requests within the collection.